# Get Excel 2007 to close completely after creating a macro in the personal macro workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I created a few macros in Excel 2007 and I saved them in the **personal macro workbook**.

Since then, I've deleted the macros. *Note: You have to unhide the workbook, delete the macro and then hide it again to accomplish this.*

Now, every time I open Excel, create/edit a workbook and click the close/exit (red X) button, Excel acts like a just closed the workbook and not the whole application. So I have to click the close/exit button one more time.

I think this is because every time Excel is opened, the personal macro workbook is opened also (only hidden). Then, when you close it, the macro workbook stays open for whatever reason.

It's annoying to have to double-click to close the application. Any ways to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have deleted all the macros from the personal macro workbook, you can delete the file `PERSONAL.XLSB`. This should cause Excel to stop doing what you described.

The file should be in one of:

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.XLSB

or

> C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART

or

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\XLStart

or similar, depending on Windows version, etc.

Comment: Perfect! On Windows XP with Office 2007, I found the PERSONAL.XLSB file in the second directory listed above. Deleted it and every works as usual now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also hold down Shift as you click the "X" to close all open workbooks and Excel completely.

Answer (score 1):

One more solution: click on the 'Office Button' in the upper left hand corner of your screen - right click on 'Exit Excel' - then choose 'Add to Quick Access Toolbar'. This will place an 'X' on your toolbar which only needs to be clicked once to close Excel completely.

Answer (score -1):

You can close Excel using ALT F4 - this will close Excel completely

Comment: This will close any program.  The author likely wants a solution that is geared towards Excel specifically.

Comment: yes but it works for Excel which is all that is needed. I find it a very useful way to close programs