# How do I prevent Excel 2007 from opening hidden workbooks, so the X button exits Excel completely?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I've been frustrated recently because Excel 2007 no longer exits when I click the upper-right X button.  Instead, it simply closes the current workbook.  I've found a partial answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/26681/get-excel-2007-to-close-completely-after-creating-a-macro-in-the-personal-macro-w): the behavior is due to the "personal macro workbook" being open and hidden.  Deleting the macros from it and deleting the workbook itself would solve the issue.
Is there a way to solve this without deleting my macros?  (Can I get Excel to stop opening this hidden workbook automatically each time it starts?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the File PERSONAL.xslb to another directory. Any file in the directory XLSTART is opened on stat up.
Then just open your personal macro file when needed.