# How do I get excel to close completely after creating a macro in a personal workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I am using Microsoft Excel 2007 and have several macros in my personal.xlsb workbook, which I use often, so it is very convenient that Excel opens them automatically when it starts. What I don't like is when I click on the "X" in the upper right corner of the window Excel does not exit when I close the last visible workbook. I think that this is because personal.xlsb is still open (though hidden). There are several other questions here on Superuser that have people [remove personal.xlsb](https://superuser.com/questions/26681/get-excel-2007-to-close-completely-after-creating-a-macro-in-the-personal-macro-w) or move it so it doesn't open on startup (question 65297) or change settings to have only one window show in the taskbar (question 86989). (Sorry there are no hyperlinks--apparently I need more reputation to add additional hyperlinks.)

I would like to have personal.xlsb open when I open Excel, have each Excel window show in the taskbar but have Excel exit when I click the "X" on the last workbook that isn't personal.xlsb. Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create code for the Workbook.SheetDeactivate Event, that checks if
 `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count =

    (1 or 0, you'll have to play with this to see which works)`

Then have it Close the Workbook if it's true.

Answer (score 3):

You need to go to the Excel options/advanced/display and uncheck Show all windows in the taskbar

Answer (score 0):

Other "workarounds" suggested (and explained more fully) [here](https://superuser.com/questions/26681/get-excel-2007-to-close-completely-after-creating-a-macro-in-the-personal-macro-w) include:

- hold down Shift as you click the red "X"
- add  'Exit Excel' to your 'Quick Access Toolbar'
- use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks, @MátéJuhász. This post was back in my newbie days. Have updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this problem without any code or special keystrokes by just opening any Excel document or creating a new one, and then closing it.  Then on the remaining blank Excel workbook, under the View menu, unhide the file `Personal.xlsb`. Re-hide it and close the blank workbook. It will prompt you to save the `Personal.xlsb`, to which you say Yes, and the problem goes away.